# How can I use AddOrUpdate in Entity Framework? Where using column identity increment

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I tried using this and it's working on add but not when updating

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //
        // Document 1 
        //
        var D1 = new database.tblDocumentEmployeeWithState
        {
            EmployeeCode = Convert.ToInt32(txtCode.Text),
            RequiredDocumentTypeCode = Convert.ToByte(txtD1Number.Text),
            DocumentStateCode = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRS1Code.Text) ? (byte?)null :  Convert.ToByte(txtRS1Code.Text), // حفظ null  لما التيكست يبقي فاضى
        };

        db.tblDocumentEmployeeWithStates.AddOrUpdate(D1);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

I get this error

> InvalidOperationException: Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported. Column: 'serial'. Table: 'PayRollModel.Store.tblDocumentEmployeeWithState'.

This is my model class: column `serial` is an identity increment in SQL

```
public partial class tblDocumentEmployeeWithState
{
    public int serial { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public byte RequiredDocumentTypeCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> DocumentStateCode { get; set; }

    public virtual tblDocumentState tblDocumentState { get; set; }
    public virtual tblEmployeeData tblEmployeeData { get; set; }
    public virtual tblRequiredDocument tblRequiredDocument { get; set; }
}
```

How can fixed this error?

Comment: You need to mark your `serial` property with `[DatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGenerated.Identity)]`and stop assigning values to it. If it is identity on the database too.

Comment: public partial class tblDocumentEmployeeWithState

    {

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]




        public int  serial { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeCode { get; set; }

}

Comment: i did that but the error Still exists

What do i do after this ?